# How do I make my website respect the spaces?(in a admin post)

Tags: html, css, django

I have a website called www.confiam.com.br, which is a django project. I have been doing some adjustment, and in the last adjustment 
I broke something from the posting paragraph, now this doesn't respect the blanks, or even when I skip some lines.

In the html I have:

```
<div class=item>
        <p><h1>{{ post.nome_evento }}</h1></p>
        <center><picture>{% cloudinary post.foto_evento %}</picture></center>
        <p><h2>{{ post.apresentacao_evento }}</h2></p>
        <br>
    </div>
```

and in the css I have:

```
p{
    text-align:justify;
}
.item h1{
    font-family: 'Kurale';
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding:20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center
}

.item h2{
    font-family: 'Kurale', serif;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center
}
```

I am going to be so much happy if somebody can help me, I have no idea what mistake I had. Very thanks everyone.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As I realized my lack of clarity, I am going to try write what the problem is. So, as my website is a django project, I had an admin interface, whit which I can post, and the post is showed in the website. But I have some issues, so I repaired my code. Before it, I started to have some formatations problems. If I put some spaces in the admin post, this isn't showed, therefore the formatation become bad. I don't have a fluent english, so I hope you understand.  Very thanks!

Comment: You could also try to ask this question on the Brazilian/Portuguese SO. Here's the link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Very thanks, but I think here is better. So, is my english readable, at least? I always try to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML normally collapses all whitespace (this allows indentation of source code, for example.)

There is a css rule `white-space` which can change this behavior; I suspect you inadvertently removed it while editing.  Depending on the exact behavior you want, you may want to set it to `pre`, `pre-line` or `pre-wrap`.   (`pre` keeps all whitespace and newlines exactly as is; `pre-wrap` is the same but also wraps lines automatically if they overflow the node width; `pre-line` preserves newlines but collapses other whitespace.)

I'm not certain from your description which DOM node needs this rule applied to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```css
div {border: 1px solid}
.demo {white-space: pre}
```

```html
<div class="demo">this
will
preserve
whitespace
</div>
<div>this
will not
preserve
whitespace
</div>
```

(You should consider using some sort of version control on your project, so that when you break things you'll be able to roll back and compare what was there previously...)

Comment: It worked, very thanks!